# Filter by multiple categories in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I would like to display only posts that are members of BOTH category 33, 39 and are post time athletes. 
My current code shows posts that are in category 33 AND 39 And athletes:

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=33&cat=39&post_type=athletes'); ?>
```

What adjustments do I need to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of options instead of a query string, in which you can use the `category__and` setting to do what you want:

```
<?php
query_posts(array(
    'category__and'  => array(33,39),
    'post_type'      => 'athletes'
));
?>
```